# Dart protoc Compilation Does Not Create gRPC Client Class

Tags: flutter, dart, grpc, protoc

My issue is that I am unable to get client code for my .proto in dart. I have a .proto that I have compiled and tested in C#/.NET Core 7.0. I've successfully deployed the server to another machine, and have interacted with it from Visual Studio running my C# client. I would like to have a dart client so that I can have my flutter application interact with the server. It took a lot of struggle, but I was eventually able to figure out how to get the autogenerated code in dart. I had started by trying to use the [Quick Start Guide](https://grpc.io/docs/languages/dart/quickstart/), but wasn't making any progress. I was able to eventually get them after finding these things:

Figured out how to actually get protoc callable from this:

https://gayan-justo.medium.com/working-with-grpc-with-flutter-on-windows-17493528e6a2

Figured out how to actually get autogenerated files from the "Compiling Your Protocol Buffers" section in this:

https://protobuf.dev/getting-started/darttutorial/

My problem is now that I can't seem to figure out how to use the autogenerated classes for a client. The output is 4 files:

```
.pb.dart
.pbenum.dart
.pbjson.dart
.pbserver.dart
```

In all of the examples I can find online, everyone appears to call a a "Client" class that is autogenerated. I don't have any "Client" code in my autogenerated files. The closest thing I have is an Api class that takes an RpcClient (an abstract class) in to it's constructor. I thought maybe I could use the Client class from the grpc package but that doesn't inherit from RpcClient and doesn't work.

```
class GpioApi {
  $pb.RpcClient _client;
  GpioApi(this._client);

  $async.Future<TimedOnResponse> timedOn($pb.ClientContext? ctx, TimedOnRequest request) =>
    _client.invoke<TimedOnResponse>(ctx, 'Gpio', 'TimedOn', request, TimedOnResponse())
  ;
  $async.Future<TimedOffResponse> timedOff($pb.ClientContext? ctx, TimedOffRequest request) =>
    _client.invoke<TimedOffResponse>(ctx, 'Gpio', 'TimedOff', request, TimedOffResponse())
  ;
}
```

My hunch is that I've got to tell protoc to compile for Client instead of Server (which you can do in C# by updating a tag in your .csproj, but I cannot find the equivalent in flutter/dart and all my google searches keep giving me these examples that just have the autogenerated code with the client classes. Is this something I can specify in the .proto? Can anyone point me in the right direction?

This is my .proto:

```
syntax = "proto3";

package gpio;

service Gpio {
  rpc TimedOn (TimedOnRequest) returns (TimedOnResponse);
  rpc TimedOff (TimedOffRequest) returns (TimedOffResponse);
}

message TimedOnRequest {
  int32 pin = 1;
  double seconds = 2;
}

message TimedOnResponse {
  bool success = 1;  
  string message = 2;
}

message TimedOffRequest {
    int32 pin = 1;
}

message TimedOffResponse {
  bool success = 1;  
  string message = 2;
}
```

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with Dart but I've answered several Dart gRPC questions. `protoc` generates stub code that is used to implement client and server code but it does not generate client and server implementations. In my experience (not only with but also with Dart), you must create and implement the client code from scratch for yourself. I recommend you use the example you cite as a template for this.

Comment: @DazWilkin take a look at this example, from the quickstart guide: https://grpc.io/docs/languages/dart/quickstart/ If you look at the helloworld example, the client imports an autogenerated client code. I'm trying to explain that I'm not getting that class. Client example: https://github.com/grpc/grpc-dart/blob/master/example/helloworld/bin/client.dart And here is the autogenerated code they are importing: https://github.com/grpc/grpc-dart/blob/master/example/helloworld/lib/src/generated/helloworld.pbgrpc.dart

Comment: `bin/client.dart` isn't generated but hand-written. Per your question, you're getting the 4 generated files that you would expect.

Comment: Please look at the other two links in my comment. The handwritten code has this line:  final stub = GreeterClient(channel); GreeterClient is not handwritten it is autogenerated. The third link in my comment is where the GreeterClient is defined and it is in the autogenerated code. Moreover, if you look at the handwritten code you can see they are importing the autogenerated code from which GreeterClient is defined

Comment: Confirm the versions of `protoc` and `protoc-gen-dart` that you're using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. From the getting started tutorial I shared in my post, they have a line as such:

protoc -I=$SRC_DIR --dart_out=$DST_DIR $SRC_DIR/gpio.proto

I had to modify it like this:

protoc -I=$SRC_DIR --dart_out=grpc:$DST_DIR $SRC_DIR/gpio.proto

The output is:

```
.pb.dart
.pbenum.dart
.pbgrpc.dart
.pbjson.dart
```

The .pbgrpc.dart has the Client class present in the examples.